# What is the ethical philosophy of American transcendentalism?

Tags: history-of-literature

The ethics of (secular) humanism is consequentialist [[1]](https://secularhumanism.org/what-is-secular-humanism/), arguably epicurean [[2]](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-secular-life/202002/what-is-secular-humanism) .
I believe the ethics of the European Enlightenment could be said epicureanism also.

But what is the ethics of American transcendentalism?

**[I don't know if this question belongs to SE Philosophy or SE Literature]**

Comment: @GarethRees "Secular Humanism frames morality as not causing unnecessary pain, harm, or suffering to humans and other animals" This is epicureanism

Comment: @GarethRees I modified my post

Comment: @GarethRees Ok, I changed the wording again. This was because to me "avoidance of unnecessary pain" is the very core tenet of epicureanism, so to share that principle is to be epicurean

Comment: I think you could split this up into two questions: one asking what the ethics of American Transcendentalism is and one asking the same about European Romanticism. The advantage of doing this, is that people who are knowledgeable about one of these movements are not necessarily knowledgeable about the other. (If you are absolutely convinced that they share the same ethics, you can keep the question as is, but I'm not sure if you would ask this question if you were.)

Comment: @Tsundoku Thanks, I just did. https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24285/what-is-the-ethical-philosophy-of-european-romanticism

Comment: This question currently has three close-votes, two of which absurdly claim that the question is "opinion-based". Close voters, please explain your reasoning.

Comment: I think the question is very reasonable, well-scoped, and entirely within the purview of this site. So I disagree with the close votes. I also think that [philosophy.se] might be an excellent place to cross-post, as it's more likely to find an answer there. If you do post it there, OP, please keep us (ha) posted with a link to that cross-post. Some of us would like to see any answers that those philosopher-kings and/or queens come up with.