# What is the ethical philosophy of European Romanticism?

Tags: history-of-literature

The ethics of (secular) humanism is consequentialist [1](https://secularhumanism.org/what-is-secular-humanism/), arguably epicurean [2](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-secular-life/202002/what-is-secular-humanism) . I believe the ethics of the European Enlightenment could be said epicureanism also.

But what is the ethics of European romanticism?

[I don't know if this question belongs to SE Philosophy or SE Literature]

Under the kind invitation of a member (see comments of this question), I cross-posted this question in SE Philosophy. Here is the link [https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97727/what-is-the-ethical-philosophy-of-european-romanticism]](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97727/what-is-the-ethical-philosophy-of-european-romanticism%5D)

Comment: This question currently has three close-votes, two of which absurdly claim that the question is "opinion-based". Close voters, please explain your reasoning.

Comment: @Tsundoku At how many "close" votes will the question be closed?

Comment: Closing a question requires five votes by non-moderators.

Comment: @Tsundoku And how many by moderators?

Comment: A single moderator vote is sufficient to close a question, but I doubt that will happen here.

Comment: I think the question is very reasonable, well-scoped, and entirely within the purview of this site. So I disagree with the close votes. I also think that Philosophy might be an excellent place to cross-post, as it's more likely to find an answer there. If you do post it there, OP, please keep us (ha) posted with a link to that cross-post. Some of us would like to see any answers that those philosopher-kings and/or queens come up with.

Comment: @verbose Dear verbos, thank you for your expression of support. I cross-posted this question in SE Philosophy, and made the required modification to this actual SE Literature question.

Comment: @verbose Do you think I should also cross-post the question about Transcendentalism's ethics? I asked whether American Transcendentalism and European Romanticism were almost identical at least in terms of principles here https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24294/the-american-transcendentalism-and-the-european-romantic-movement-of-the-19th-ce

Comment: yes, I believe I made the identical comment on that question as well