# The American Transcendentalism and the European Romantic movement of the 19th century

Tags: history-of-literature

In the paragraph concerning the American Transcendentalism movement, the [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/american-philosophy/) lists the following features defining this movement:

- emphasis on the subjective nature of human experience and existence
- highlighting often even a fairly mystical holism,
- argument for the priority of personal non-cognitive, emotional connections to nature and to the world as a whole. Human are agents in the world more fundamentally than they are knowers of the world.
- claim that “Real” knowledge is intuitive and personal; it transcends scientific understanding that is based on empirical sense experience.
- transcending those things that constrain or restrict free personal thought, such as conventional morality and political institutions
- argument for the importance of self-reliance, intuition, and a return to nature, i.e., an embracing of what is non-civilized and non-industrial.
- holding an idealist philosophical stance over a materialist philosophical stance

It seems to me that all these features are shared by the European Romantic movement of the 19th century (which took place mainly in Germany, in Great Britain, and France).

Is it correct that both the American Transcendentalism and the European Romantic movement of the 19th century share the features listed above?